# Cost-effective solution to connecting many SATA hard disks to a Linux laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, hard-disk, sata, low-cost

What I have:

1. Linux laptop with the usual connectors (most importantly, probably: USB)
2. multiple (about 4-6) SATA hard disks

My goal is to connect them simultanously, i.e. I want to manipulate all the hard disks from the Linux laptop.

The solution does not need to be mobile any more (so a jungle of various cables is okay).

Using multiple USB-SATA connectors is viable *only if there will be no power problems*. Note: USB has max 5V and 2A, which is barely enough even for a single HDD (note: they were designed for working internally in desktop machines, where power is a no-issue).

So the question is the lowest cost option to externally attack multiple SATA disk to a laptop.

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate disks"? Have you consider using NAS?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am actively boycotting the NAS concept because the available solutions are costly and s...uboptimal.

Comment: My personal consideration: NAS offer me all the options I need and I pay with money. Someone else will pay with his/her time to build such configuration and options. :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Beside that all the solutions I have found until now, are s...uboptimal, also my problem is that I would pay for some sw config what also I can do. I would also pay for unneeded hardware what I already have. My problem is not that I can not config a linux server, my problem is that I can not attach the hard disks to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some external docking station for multiple HDD, where you can access your data via USB or SATA but you have to power the docking with external cables, here you have a link to what is these docking station: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/hard-drive-docking-station.html

You only have to find the docking station that respects your standard.